# Storing char array column into string for comparison

Tags: java, char, equality

I have a char array[4][4] of single characters ie. 'a' and I'm trying to store just the columns of the array into a string for comparison to another string. But the issue I have is it keeps adding the original element to the string. My code below contains the words "car" & "trip" in the array, and want to compare it to another string with those words to make it true. Here is my code:

```
char[][] puzzle = {{'a', 'c', 'h' ,'t'}, 
                   {'v', 'a', 'x', 'r'}, 
                   {'x', 'r', 'e', 'i'}, 
                   {'c', 'q', 'i', 'p'}
                  };

for(int row=0; row<puzzle.length; row++)
{

  String match = "";
  String matchword ="";
  for(int col=0; col<puzzle.length; col++)
  {
   match += puzzle[col][row];
   System.out.print(match);
  }
 System.out.println();
}
```

The output to the string is as follows:
aavavxavxc
ccacarcarq
hhxhxehxei
ttrtritrip

instead of:
avxc
carq
hxei
trip

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are printing match on every iteration of the loop.

You should only print when the loop is finished.

```
for(int col=0; col<puzzle.length; col++)
{
    match += puzzle[col][row];
}
System.out.println(match);
```

Currently match is

```
a
av
avx
avxc
```

But since you print them all on one line you get

```
aavavxavxc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if I've understood what you're asking correctly.

```
    char[][] puzzle = {
                        {'a', 'c', 'h' ,'t'}, 
                       {'v', 'a', 'x', 'r'}, 
                       {'x', 'r', 'e', 'i'}, 
                       {'c', 'q', 'i', 'p'}
                      };

    String output = "";
    //we need to go throug the entire set of rows, but the tricky bit is in getting just say the first set of values [1][1], [2][1]... 
    //rather than getting the exterior as you were previously. 

    //Start by selecting element 1, 2, 3 from the outer array
    for(int i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i ++) {

        //Then perform the inner loop
        for(int j = 0; j < puzzle[i].length; j++) {
            output = output + puzzle[j][i]; //Here being the trick, select the inner loop first (j) and the inner second. Thus working your way through 'columns' 
        }

        output = output +"\n"; 
    }

    System.out.println(output);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression based on your array `puzzle[][]`

```
        char[][] puzzle = {{'a', 'c', 'h' ,'t'}, 
            {'v', 'a', 'x', 'r'}, 
            {'x', 'r', 'e', 'i'}, 
            {'c', 'q', 'i', 'p'}
           };

    // regex array
    String[] regexs = new String[puzzle.length];

    int counter = 0;
    for(int row=0; row<puzzle.length; row++) {
        String match = "[";

        for (int col = 0; col < puzzle.length; col++) {
            match += puzzle[col][row];
            match += ",";
        }

        // Add regular expression into array
        regexs[counter] = match + "]";

        counter++;
    }

    // Prepare
    Pattern p = null;
    Matcher m = null;

    // Now parse with your inputs
    for(String arg : args) {

        for(String regex : regexs) {
            p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            m = p.matcher(arg);

            if(m.find()) {
                System.out.println(">>> OK. input: "+arg+" and matcher:"+regex);
            } else {
                // other output
            }
        }
    }
```

You can enjoy to create some addition to your regular expressions.